# jruby trouble with warbler aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, warbler

I'm a beginner in jruby. I have a Ruby Rails app - which I run with rials s to run. Now I want to create war-warbler with a WAR-file, but I get an error with which I can do nothing:

`double loading C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.21/lib/arjdbc/tasks/databases.rake please delete lib/tasks/jdbc.rake if present!
warble aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method 'tail' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  taint
rakefile:1:in`
`rakefile:6:in`
`C:/Hagen/leaman/lib/tasks/warbler/warbler.rake:1:in`
`C:/Hagen/leaman/lib/tasks/warbler/warbler.rake:2:in`
`rakefile:1:in`
`rakefile:6:in`
`C:/Hagen/leaman/lib/tasks/warbler/warbler.rake:1:in`
`C:/Hagen/leaman/lib/tasks/warbler/warbler.rake:2:in`
`rakefile:1:in`
`rakefile:6:in`` '

facts:
windows7
Jruby-9.1.5.0
Warbler (2.0.4)

EDIT:
If I call the following `jruby -S warble --trace` I get the following trace:
countless times:
`double loading C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.21/lib/arjdbc/tasks/databases.rake please delete lib/tasks/jdbc.rake if present!`

and then thereafter:

`warble aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method 'tail' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  taint
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:221:in 'in_namespace'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:140:in 'namespace'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:3:in'<main>'org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'block in load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in 'load_dependency'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:51:in 'block in Railtie' org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1704:in 'instance_exec'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:237:in 'block in run_tasks_blocks'org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in 'each'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:245:in 'each_registered_block'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:237:in 'run_tasks_blocks'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:451:in 'block in run_tasks_blocks'org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in 'each'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in 'each'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:451:in 'run_tasks_blocks'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:453:in 'load_tasks'
rakefile:1:in '<main>'org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'block in load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in 'load_dependency'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/application.rb:61:in 'block in load_project_rakefile'org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in 'each'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/application.rb:58:in 'load_project_rakefile'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler.rb:26:in 'project_application'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/traits/rails.rb:27:in 'before_configure'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/traits.rb:29:in 'block in before_configure'org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in 'each'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/traits.rb:29:in 'before_configure'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/config.rb:215:in 'initialize'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/task.rb:48:in 'initialize'
rakefile:6:in '<main>'org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'block in load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in 'load_dependency'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:658:in 'block in run_tasks_blocks'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:658:in 'run_tasks_blocks'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:452:in 'run_tasks_blocks'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:453:in 'load_tasks'
C:/Hagen/leaman/lib/tasks/warbler/warbler.rake:1:in '<main>'org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'block in load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in 'load_dependency'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/application.rb:61:in 'block in load_project_rakefile'org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in 'each'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/application.rb:58:in 'load_project_rakefile'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler.rb:26:in 'project_application'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/traits/rails.rb:27:in 'before_configure'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/traits.rb:29:in 'block in before_configure'org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in 'each'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/traits.rb:29:in 'before_configure'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/config.rb:215:in 'initialize'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/task.rb:48:in 'initialize'
C:/Hagen/leaman/lib/tasks/warbler/warbler.rake:2:in '<main>'org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'block in load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in 'load_dependency'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:658:in 'block in run_tasks_blocks'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:658:in 'run_tasks_blocks'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:452:in 'run_tasks_blocks'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:453:in 'load_tasks'
rakefile:1:in '<main>'org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'block in load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in 'load_dependency'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/application.rb:61:in 'block in load_project_rakefile'org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in 'each'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/application.rb:58:in 'load_project_rakefile'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler.rb:26:in 'project_application'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/traits/rails.rb:27:in 'before_configure'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/traits.rb:29:in 'block in before_configure'org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in 'each'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/traits.rb:29:in 'before_configure'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/config.rb:215:in 'initialize'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/task.rb:48:in 'initialize'
rakefile:6:in '<main>'org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'block in load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in 'load_dependency'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:658:in 'block in run_tasks_blocks'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:658:in 'run_tasks_blocks'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:452:in 'run_tasks_blocks'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:453:in 'load_tasks'
C:/Hagen/leaman/lib/tasks/warbler/warbler.rake:1:in '<main>'org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'block in load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in 'load_dependency'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/application.rb:61:in 'block in load_project_rakefile'org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in 'each'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/application.rb:58:in 'load_project_rakefile'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler.rb:26:in 'project_application'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/traits/rails.rb:27:in 'before_configure'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/traits.rb:29:in 'block in before_configure'org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in 'each'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/traits.rb:29:in 'before_configure'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/config.rb:215:in 'initialize'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/task.rb:48:in 'initialize
C:/Hagen/leaman/lib/tasks/warbler/warbler.rake:2:in '<main>'org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'block in load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in 'load_dependency'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_supp
ort/dependencies.rb:268:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:658:in 'block in run_tasks_blocks'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:658:in 'run_tasks_blocks'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:452:in 'run_tasks_blocks'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:453:in 'load_tasks'
rakefile:1:in '<main>'org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'block in load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in 'load_dependency'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in 'load'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/application.rb:61:in 'block in load_project_rakefile'org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in 'each'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/application.rb:58:in 'load_project_rakefile'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler.rb:26:in 'project_application'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/traits/rails.rb:27:in 'before_configure'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/traits.rb:29:in 'block in before_configure'org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in 'each'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/traits.rb:29:in 'before_configure'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/config.rb:215:in 'initialize'
C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/warbler-2.0.4/lib/warbler/task.rb:48:in 'initialize' 
rakefile:6:in '<main>'`

Comment: a bit weird, is this your full trace after simply running `jruby -S warble` ?

Comment: @kares i have edited the entry.

Comment: that double loading part might relate to the problem -> possibly you might want to isolate (e.g. print a backtrace each time __FILE__ is loaded) why its happening. it is probably a loading bug but maybe Windows specific, hard to tell without having a reproduction case and Windows around :)

Comment: @kares how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all.
I have reinstalled JRuby and then it worked.